# Como mudar o innerHTML de uma DIV, sendo que tem outros elementos dentro dela que não podem ser alterados?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um blog e a atribuição deste blog está incorreta e nem mesmo alterando funciona. Queria utilizar um script que alterasse o innerHTML dentro desta DIV mas sem alterar outros conteúdos.

Exemplo:

```
function setAttrib(nameof, content){
document.getElementById(nameof).innerHTML=content;
}
```

Mas o problema é que dentro desta DIV existe outros itens dentro dela que não posso alterar e o único item que eu quero alterar seria uma outra DIV sem ID mas tem ClassName, porém comom é um Blog tem vários ClassName do mesmo tipo.

Observe:

[image: HTML SOUCE CODE VIEW]

Observe que na imagem o ID Attribution1 é o item que eu quero alterar mas tem outros itens dentro desta DIV.

Comment: sim a posição do elemento é fixa!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o elemento interno for o com a classe `widget-content`, faça assim:

```
document.querySelector('#Attribution1 .widget-content').innerHTML = 'sei lá';
```

Comment: é sim. mas precisa de jQuery ou outra lib pra rodar este script?

Comment: Não, isso é JavaScript puro (que funciona até no IE8).

Comment: ok vou testar este script e vou avaliar sua resposta.

Comment: funcionou corretamente! obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Legal, que bom que ajudou!